# Find result within Array of Objects and match email address field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm trying to match the `emailAddress` field and the `page_slug`. Currently I'm using the following which matches just the about page in the modularSequence:

```
db.getCollection('users').find({"modularSequence.page_slug": "about"}, {"modularSequence.$": 1 })
```

This works and returns:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5740c631742da6e83389abb4"),
    "modularSequence" : [ 
        {
            "page_id" : "1",
            "sequence" : "m_1",
            "category" : "headers",
            "page_slug" : "about"
        }
    ]
}
```

Which it half what I want. I'm looking to return the emailAddress field as well. I've tried using this but it returns everything and multiple modular elements:

```
db.getCollection('users').find({$and:[{"emailAddress": 'paul@example.com'}, {"modularSequence.page_slug": "about"}, {"modularSequence": {$elemMatch: {page_slug:'about'}}}]})

[
  {
    "emailAddress": "paul@example.com",
    "modularSequence": [
      {
        "page_slug": "about",
        "category": "headers",
        "sequence": "m_1",
        "page_id": "1"
      },
      {
        "page_slug": "contact",
        "category": "content",
        "sequence": "m_4",
        "page_id": "2"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

How do I match both the emailAddress field and the modularSequence.page_slug - only return a result if both the email address matches and the page_slug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `$and` array is including your field selection parameter as well. But you don't need to use `$and` here anyway as multiple query terms are implicitly ANDed by default, so you can simplify your query to:

```
db.users.find({"emailAddress": 'paul@example.com', "modularSequence.page_slug": "about"},
              {"emailAddress": 1, "modularSequence.$": 1})
```

Which is your first query, but with an `emailAddress` field added to both the query and field selection parameters.

The first parameter of [`find`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#db.collection.find) is the query (*which* docs), and the second is the projection (which *fields* within those docs), so that's why those fields are there twice. The `$` in the projection represents the `modularSequence` array element matched in the query.

Comment: That's perfect, thank you very much. A few questions just so I fully understand what's going on as opposed to just C&P'in this. I'm guessing the "emailAddress": 1 is specifying we want the emailAddress from the top level, and "modularSequence.$": 1 - is doing the same but for $ to represent page_slug. The one thing I don't quite understand is why we are specifying emailAddress & modularSequence twice?

Comment: The first parameter of [`find`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#db.collection.find) is the query (which docs), and the second is the projection (which fields within those docs), so that's why those fields are there twice. The `$` in the projection represents the `modularSequence` array element matched in the query.

Comment: One last @JohnnyHK, if I was to allow for multiple occurrences of 'about' within the objects, how would I allow for this?

Comment: @DennisTurn That's a trickier case. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/12241930/1259510